# Recognition of stack-bases language

Tags: javascript, programming-languages, stack-based

Does anyone know what language this could be?

```
    ([][(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][[]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])
    [+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!!)[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is javascript, see here http://forum.lessthandot.com/viewtopic.php?f=44&t=13503

put this in a file and run it

```
<script type="text/javascript">([][(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!

[]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])

[+[]]][([][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!!

[]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]]()[(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])

[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]])([][(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])

[+[]]+(![]+[]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!

+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]][([][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!!

[]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!

[]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]]()[([][(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!

+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]][([][(!

[]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!

+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]]()+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!!

[]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])

[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]](+[]+[+[]])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])

[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[!

+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(+[![]]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])

[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+!+[]]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+([][(!

[]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!

+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!!

[]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!

+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(+[![]]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[]+[][[]])[+!

+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+!+[]]]+(!![]+[])[!

+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!

+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+[][(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[]

[(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!

+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]][([][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!

+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!

+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]]()[(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])

[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!!

[]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])

[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]][([][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!

+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!

+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]]()+[])[!+[]+!+[]]](+[]+([][(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[]+[][[]])[+!

+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!

+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]][([][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!

+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]]()+[])[!+[]+!

+[]+!+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]])[+!+[]])</script>
```

another example

```
<script type="text/javascript">($=[$=[]][(__=!$+$)[_=-~-~-~$]+({}+$)[_/_]+
($$=($_=!''+$)[_/_]+$_[+$])])()[__[_/_]+__
[_+~$]+$_[_]+$$]('I am cool')</script>
```

Comment: Wow! This is correct. This is an option a would have never thought about! Thanks!